# What is the maximum inventory capacity of the exosuit?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've found many resources talking about how to increase the number of inventory slots on the exosuit by finding drop pods or various npc interactions, but none of these have stated how many times you can upgrade this way.

What is the maximum number of inventory slots you can get on an exosuit? (through drop pods or other methods).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After much time spent playing I have finally upgraded my exosuit to the max. 48 slots is the maximum you can have. 8 across and 6 down. The final upgrade costs 350,000 units. You will know that this is the last upgrade because no prompt to upgrade the exosuit is shown after the 48th slot.